# Understanding dpi and the drawable folders

Tags: android, android-layout

Yesterday I already asked a question about this here. After that I saw this on the official android developer page:

[image]

So you can have a `1024x600px` screen device with `ldpi` and a screen with the same resolution with `mdpi`.

Furthermore you can have a `600x1024px` screen device with `mdpi` and a screen with the same resolution with `hdpi`.

I have an image, that takes 20 % of the screen's height and width on every device.

I want to make 5 versions of that image (with different resolution) for each drawable folder.

In my past thread I got this answer:

```
ldpi:    0.75
mdpi:    1.0
hdpi:    1.5
xhdpi:   2.0  
xxhdpi:  3.0  
xxxhdpi: 4.0
```

These are the scale factors.

So if my image has a resolution of 50 x 100 px in mdpi it is supposed to have a resolution of 75 x 150 px in hdpi.

I understand that. 
The question now is, how am I supposed to know what resolution my image should have in the mdpi folder, if the resolutions for mdpi are totally different (as you can see in the image above -> from 320x480 to 1280x768).

Thanks !

Comment: For phones, you normally use the drawable-hdpi naming, For tablets, you normally use the drawable-swXYZdp-hdpi naming - being XYZ the minimum width (so, the width it has in portrait mode)

Answer (score 0):

The drawables should be created at a resolution that makes them the right physical size when displayed on the screen.  If you have an icon that is supposed to be 1/2 inch by 1/2 inch on an MDPI screen, then the image should be 80px by 80px.  This size should be irregardless of the physical dimensions of the screen; the same drawable on a 1280x768 MDPI tablet is supposed to be 1/2 inch by 1/2inch.

If the icon in question should be larger on the tablet for some reason, then you would need to introduce the drawable-swXYZdp-mdpi folder that Der Golem mentioned above.  In this folder, you would be able to create a version of the icon that had a larger physical size (say 3/4 inch) that will be loaded on the tablet.